# Why does not my opamp-latch work as I expect?

Tags: operational-amplifier

See schematic:

[image]

Opamp is OPA2132. (I forgot to draw a resistor in schematic: just at the V is an 8k2)

U is fixed 5V, making in+ about 4.4V reference.
V is square wave, either 5V or 1V.

```
If V=5, X~=5
If V=1, X~=1
```

No problems there.

The purpose of the BJT-feedback is that if V=1, X goes high, BJT (BC547) gets saturated and pulls in- down. Emitter-resistor is 1k.

In- is in the voltage divider of 8k2/1k.

In theory, and in my simulations, this latch should work: as soon as the BJT is saturated, in- is kept low and will not ever make the opamp go low again.

But, on my breadboard, as soon as the BJT-feedback is connected, the opamp-output is always high, no matter what V is. I started with V=5 and never switched it, but the feedback is somehow triggering.

If I break the feedback (either pull BJT, diode or resistor), the opamp behaves as expected (except for the latch ofcourse). Same goes if the BJT stays but doesn't get any base current.

So, something here makes the base conduct and make the BJT latch immediately, but I cannot find out what, since exactly this circuit works in my simulator.

Have I done some obvious error?

Comment: Have you considered that during the startup of the circuit, the latching condition might be present while the rails and signals are rising.

Comment: On power-up, your latch may trigger as the rails rise and never clear. Use a resistor instead of the diode. Add a capacitor (1uF/10uF total guess value) in parallel with the in+ resistor to ground. Then power it up and see if it's not latched.

Comment: You could unlatch it by temporarily shorting B to ground, and then see whether your circuit works as expected.

Comment: The Opamp needs satisfactory rails. Older opamps only met spec for +-12 to +-18 volts. What does the datasheet require, for your choice of opamp?

Comment: @dave tweed: unlatching by shorting B to ground works as expected. Tony is right; the latch occurs at power up since in- is slower than in+. Adding an RC-filter to in+ does not help. I will have to re-think this circuit.